# search results only from post title, category and tags

Tags: wordpress, search

If it is default WordPress search or custom search form, If only matched the search text in a post title, category and tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below query can get solution,

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            's' => $keyword,
            'cat' => $catSearchID,
            'tag'   => $tag-slug,
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'location' => $post_location_search ,
        );

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

The search form should like this.

```
<form class="search" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
  <input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search&hellip;">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
  <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="kb_article">
</form>
```

We’ll name our custom search results templates using the WordPress filename conventions of {template}-{post_type}.php. In our case, that would result in search-kb_article.php. We could just check to see if that post_type=kb_article is set in the URL string and use get_template_part to load it if it is, but let’s go a step further. We’ll check to see if post_type is set in the URL string, and if it is, also check to see if custom search template exists for that post type using the {template}-{post_type}.php naming pattern. If it does, we’ll load it. If not, we’ll continue with the default search template.

```
<?php
// store the post type from the URL string
$post_type = $_GET['post_type'];
// check to see if there was a post type in the
// URL string and if a results template for that
// post type actually exists
if ( isset( $post_type ) && locate_template( 'search-' . $post_type . '.php' ) ) {
  // if so, load that template
  get_template_part( 'search', $post_type );

  // and then exit out
  exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: No. I am asking results fetch, not to override the default search template.